UTC Now using boost Posix Time with nanoseconds precision
Is there a way to get the ptime representation of the current UTC time using boost Posix Time Library with nanoseconds precision? I know how to get microseconds precision using microsec_clock. I know as well we can get this using chrono:
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> pt = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
const auto nanos = static_cast<std::time_t>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(pt.time_since_epoch()).count());

Looking for something like nanosec_clock maybe?
Note: I am using boost library so I would like to keep using it for this as well, if no solution I could use the chrono above explained here as well.

This question is similar to: C++ current system time in nanoseconds as long integer in order to send influxdb. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As explained in my question I would like to stay consistent and use same library instead of chrono. That is the difference with that question. I added a Note in the question. Thank you

Note that just because an API returns nanoseconds does not mean that is has nanoseconds precision, you will need to check this.


PTime - Introduction
Defines a non-adjusted time system with nano-second/micro-second resolution and stable calculation properties. The nano-second resolution option uses 96 bits of underlying storage for each ptime while the micro-second resolution uses 64 bits per ptime (see Build Options for details).

From Build Options:
Compilation Options
By default the posix_time system uses a single 64 bit integer internally to provide a microsecond level resolution. As an alternative, a combination of a 64 bit integer and a 32 bit integer (96 bit resolution) can be used to provide nano-second level resolutions. The default implementation may provide better performance and more compact memory usage for many applications that do not require nano-second resolutions.
To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG must be defined in the library users project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc).

Hi @Ted Lyngmo thanks so much for this. I already defined that flag using #define BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG in one of my hpp. Do you think this will enable nanosec_clock and does it even exist in boost libarary? Because what I need is more precise than just using the nanoseconds. I want a way to get the current UTC time in nanoseconds

@SpeakX You're welcome! I would define it outside the source code (as an argument to the compiler, g++ -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG ...) to ensure that no boost headers are read before it is defined.
